# When using the singleton design pattern, do other methods need to use synchronized keyword to ensure thread safety?

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

I want to ensure that the following class is thread-safe, should I use the synchronized keyword for other methods? Or use a thread-safe data structure to store Email. What should I do?

```
public class RecycleStation {
    private static volatile RecycleStation uniqueInstance;
    private static List<Email> recycleEmailList ;

    private RecycleStation() {
        recycleEmailList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public static RecycleStation getInstance() {
        if (uniqueInstance == null) {
            synchronized (RecycleStation.class) {
                if (uniqueInstance == null) {
                    uniqueInstance = new RecycleStation();
                }
            }
        }
        return uniqueInstance;
    }

    public void RecycleEmail(Email email) {
        recycleEmailList.add(email);
    }

    public void deleteEmail(Email email) {
        recycleEmailList.remove(email);
    }

    public void clear() {
        recycleEmailList.clear();
    }

}
```

Comment: This is a good question; however I do feel with research you can find better answers than those which I can provide. Read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289105/java-preferred-design-for-using-a-mutable-object-reference-in-another-thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, [a Singleton pattern is best implemented as Enum in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26292956/407953)
Second, each `email` manipulation function (`clear`, `Recycle`, `delete`) [should be synchronized to ensure thread safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531873/how-thread-safe-is-enum-in-java) (the link is about an Enum, but the same holds about each and every Sinlgeton implementation):

```
public synchronized void RecycleEmail(Email email)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use a `thread-safe`, `atomic` data structure for your Emails than setting `synchronized` in each of the update methods. Synchronization uses the `lock` mechanism of the OS, which is an expensive operation and should be avoided.

I'd use `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` (example below).

Regarding the class itself - The [Lazy-Initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization) design pattern for a thread-safe singleton might be a good solution too.

It has mostly pro's in your case:

- You avoid the use of `synchronized` in `getInstance()`
- Slightly improves start-up time
- Thread-safe :)

**Edit:** Have a look at [this article](https://crunchify.com/lazy-creation-of-singleton-threadsafe-instance-without-using-synchronized-keyword/) to better understand why this implementation is thread-safe. @Rafael has made a good point: lazy Initialization, by its own, doesn't necessarily mean thread-safety.

After all is said and done, here's an implementation:

```java
public class RecycleStation  {
    private static RecycleStation uniqueInstance; //You don't need `volatile` here
    private static ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Email> recycleEmailList;

    // Here it all begins:
    private static class SingletonHolder {
        private static RecycleStation  instance = new RecycleStation();
    }
    public static RecycleStation getInstance() {
        return SingletonHolder.instance;
    }
    private RecycleStation () {
        recycleEmailList = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
    }

    // class functions:
    public void RecycleEmail(Email email) {
        recycleEmailList.add(email);
    }

    public void deleteEmail(Email email) {
        recycleEmailList.remove(email);
    }

    public void clear() {
        recycleEmailList = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
    }
}
```

Comment: How can you assume that's thread-safe. What if two threads try to lazily initialize the singleton simultaneously? Lazy initialization and thread-safety are two different things.

Comment: That's a good point, I had to give a little further explanation for this specific implementation: The `SingletonHolder` class won't be loaded until we reference it. This means that when we import the `RecyclerStation` class, the instance won't be created until the moment the `getInstance() `method is called (the `SingletonHolder` is referenced). Since only a single thread loads classes (which is the main thread only in this case), only one instance will be created, and therefore - thread-safety & lazy initialization. But correct me if I have any mistake.

Comment: Have a look at [this article](https://crunchify.com/lazy-creation-of-singleton-threadsafe-instance-without-using-synchronized-keyword/)

Comment: How can it be thread safe if more than one thread will use functions that manipulate `email` list???

Comment: Another good point. I was too focused on the class initialization - I fixed my answer. However, be advised that setting the methods to `synchronized` isn't the most efficient solution in terms of speed. Have a look at my edit.